# Connecting to remote database using SSMS 2016 - backup and restore functions not available

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssms

I've set up an Azure SQL server (version V12) and have no problem connecting to it from my local computer via SSMS 2016 and using SQL Server Authentication. However, when I right click on a database and point to Tasks, the backup and restore options are not available. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup and restore for Azure SQL DB are done using the Azure portal. Alternately, you can use the "Export Data-Tier Application" feature in SSMS to export a bacpac file with the schema + data of your database. (Note that exporting a bacpac file should not be done against a live database whose values are changing, because unlike backup/restore, export does not guarantee transactional consistency. If values in tables are changing during an export operation, the export will fail.)